# Is it possible to get data from a website to populate a database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, jsoup, recipe

So, my app is, essentially, a recipe search app. I have a database that holds all the recipes. But, I need a large amount of recipes initially to show all the features. So, would it be possible to pull recipes from a website and somehow insert them into my database?

Comment: You can try [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to extract data from a website, or use an [API](https://www.google.ie/search?q=recipe+database+api), or find a downloadable text database somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible. You can get data with a web service and insert to your sqlite database which your app uses. Here's an example of Sqlite Db. Here's an example of a word game which has a relational db model. I hope this'll help you.

SQLiteHelper:

```
public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "RotatingCards.db";


    public static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES = "";

    public SQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // CREATE STATEMENTS
        db.execSQL(EntryContract.ExamsEntry.CREATE_STATEMENT);
        db.execSQL(EntryContract.SubjectsEntry.CREATE_STATEMENT);
        db.execSQL(EntryContract.WordsEntry.CREATE_STATEMENT);
        db.execSQL(EntryContract.WordsToExamEntry.CREATE_STATEMENT);

        // POPULATE STATEMENTS
        db.execSQL(EntryContract.ExamsEntry.POPULATE_STATEMENT);
        db.execSQL(EntryContract.SubjectsEntry.POPULATE_STATEMENT);
        db.execSQL(EntryContract.WordsEntry.POPULATE_STATEMENT);
        db.execSQL(EntryContract.WordsToExamEntry.POPULATE_STATEMENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
}
```

Your custom SQLiteHelper

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteHelper {

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public List<Exam> getAllExams() {
        List<Exam> exams = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM " + EntryContract.ExamsEntry.TABLE_NAME;
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    exams.add(new Exam(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                            cursor.getString(1),
                            cursor.getString(2),
                            cursor.getString(3)));
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
                cursor.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return exams;
    }

    public List<Subject> getSubjectsByExam(int examId) {
        List<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
            String query = "SELECT DISTINCT se." + EntryContract._ID + ", se." + EntryContract.SubjectsEntry.COLUMN_NAME + ", se." + EntryContract.SubjectsEntry.COLUMN_DESC +
                    " FROM " + EntryContract.SubjectsEntry.TABLE_NAME + " AS se INNER JOIN " + EntryContract.WordsToExamEntry.TABLE_NAME
                    + " AS wte WHERE se." + EntryContract._ID + "= wte." + EntryContract.WordsToExamEntry.COLUMN_SUBJECT
                    + " AND wte." + EntryContract.WordsToExamEntry.COLUMN_EXAM_ID + "=" + examId;
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    subjects.add(new Subject(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                            cursor.getString(1),
                            cursor.getString(2)));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return subjects;
    }
}
```

And here're statments:

```
public final class EntryContract {
    public EntryContract() {
    }

    public static final String _ID = "_id";

    public static abstract class ExamsEntry implements BaseColumns {

        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "exam_details";
        public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "exam_title";
        public static final String COLUMN_SHORT_TITLE = "short_title";
        public static final String COLUMN_DESC = "desc";

        public static final String CREATE_STATEMENT =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (\"" + _ID + "\" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , \""
                        + COLUMN_TITLE + "\" TEXT NOT NULL  UNIQUE," +
                        " \"" + COLUMN_SHORT_TITLE + "\" TEXT NOT NULL  UNIQUE, \"" + COLUMN_DESC + "\" TEXT); ";

        public static final String POPULATE_STATEMENT = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " VALUES" +
                "(0,'TOEFL','toefl','Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc porta feugiat magna, non venenatis orci blandit ac. Proin non condimentum lectus. Morbi ultricies urna sit amet nunc consectetur dignissim. Sed accumsan, dolor non vulputate vestibulum, risus augue viverra justo, vitae feugiat mauris elit quis felis. Nunc tristique et erat at fringilla. Pellentesque pulvinar odio vel nisl ultricies consequat. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent vehicula urna id quam convallis, vitae egestas odio vehicula. Nam rhoncus diam ipsum.')," +
                "(1,'YDS','yds','Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc porta feugiat magna, non venenatis orci blandit ac. Proin non condimentum lectus. Morbi ultricies urna sit amet nunc consectetur dignissim. Sed accumsan, dolor non vulputate vestibulum, risus augue viverra justo, vitae feugiat mauris elit quis felis. Nunc tristique et erat at fringilla. Pellentesque pulvinar odio vel nisl ultricies consequat. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent vehicula urna id quam convallis, vitae egestas odio vehicula. Nam rhoncus diam ipsum.')," +
                "(2,'GRE','gre','Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc porta feugiat magna, non venenatis orci blandit ac. Proin non condimentum lectus. Morbi ultricies urna sit amet nunc consectetur dignissim. Sed accumsan, dolor non vulputate vestibulum, risus augue viverra justo, vitae feugiat mauris elit quis felis. Nunc tristique et erat at fringilla. Pellentesque pulvinar odio vel nisl ultricies consequat. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent vehicula urna id quam convallis, vitae egestas odio vehicula. Nam rhoncus diam ipsum. ')," +
                "(3,'Kids','kids','Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc porta feugiat magna, non venenatis orci blandit ac. Proin non condimentum lectus. Morbi ultricies urna sit amet nunc consectetur dignissim. Sed accumsan, dolor non vulputate vestibulum, risus augue viverra justo, vitae feugiat mauris elit quis felis. Nunc tristique et erat at fringilla. Pellentesque pulvinar odio vel nisl ultricies consequat. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent vehicula urna id quam convallis, vitae egestas odio vehicula. Nam rhoncus diam ipsum. ')," +
                "(4,'Benim Kelimelerim','benim-kelimelerim','Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc porta feugiat magna, non venenatis orci blandit ac. Proin non condimentum lectus. Morbi ultricies urna sit amet nunc consectetur dignissim. Sed accumsan, dolor non vulputate vestibulum, risus augue viverra justo, vitae feugiat mauris elit quis felis. Nunc tristique et erat at fringilla. Pellentesque pulvinar odio vel nisl ultricies consequat. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent vehicula urna id quam convallis, vitae egestas odio vehicula. Nam rhoncus diam ipsum. ');";
    }

    public static abstract class SubjectsEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "subject_details";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "subject_name";
        public static final String COLUMN_DESC = "desc";

        public static final String CREATE_STATEMENT = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (\"" + _ID + "\" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE , \""
                + COLUMN_NAME + "\" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,"
                + " \"" + COLUMN_DESC + "\" TEXT); ";

        public static final String POPULATE_STATEMENT = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " VALUES" +
                "(0,'Sıfatlar','Sıfatları içerir')," +
                "(1,'Zarflar','Zarfları içerir')," +
                "(2,'Bağlaçlar','Bağlaçları içerir')," +
                "(3,'İsimler','İsimleri içerir');" +
                "(4,'Phrasel Verbs','Phrasel Verbs içerir');";

    }

    public static abstract class WordsEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "words";
        public static final String COLUMN_EN = "word_en";
        public static final String COLUMN_TR = "word_tr";
        public static final String COLUMN_EN_DESC = "en_desc";
        public static final String COLUMN_TR_DESC = "tr_desc";
        public static final String COLUMN_FAV = "is_favorited";

        public static final String CREATE_STATEMENT = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (\"" + _ID + "\" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE , \""
                + COLUMN_EN + "\" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, \""
                + COLUMN_TR + "\" TEXT NOT NULL, \""
                + COLUMN_EN_DESC + "\" TEXT NOT NULL, \""
                + COLUMN_TR_DESC + "\" TEXT NOT NULL, \""
                + COLUMN_FAV + "\" INTEGER NOT NULL);";

        public static final String POPULATE_STATEMENT = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " VALUES" +
                "(0,'And','Ve', 'And','Ve bağlacı','0');";
    }

    public static abstract class WordsToExamEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "words_to_subject";
        public static final String COLUMN_EXAM_ID = "exam_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_WORD_ID = "word_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_DIFFICULTY = "dif_level";
        public static final String COLUMN_SUBJECT = "subject_id";

        public static final String CREATE_STATEMENT = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (\"" + _ID + "\" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE , \""
                + COLUMN_EXAM_ID + "\" INTEGER NOT NULL, \""
                + COLUMN_WORD_ID + "\" INTEGER NOT NULL, \""
                + COLUMN_DIFFICULTY + "\" INTEGER NOT NULL, \""
                + COLUMN_SUBJECT + "\" INTEGER NOT NULL);";

        public static final String POPULATE_STATEMENT = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " VALUES" +
                "(0,0,0,1,2);";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in your activity

```
  class updateMed extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.connexEnCours));
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {



        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1","value1"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2","value2"));
        json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(your url,
                "POST", params);


        try {
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(json));
            if(json != null && !json.isNull("success")){
            int success = json.getInt("success");

            if (success == 1) {
                if (json.getString("type").equals("update")) {
                    JSONArray ja = json.getJSONArray("med");
                    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                        Integer Cle = c.getInt("Cle");
                        String Nom = c.getString("Nom");
                        String Prenom = c.getString("Prenom");
                        String Adresse = c.getString("Adresse");
                        String Numero = c.getString("Numero");
                        String Lat = c.getString("Lat");
                        String Lng = c.getString("Lng");
                        String Specialite = c.getString("Specialite");
                        Specialite = avoirSpe(Specialite);
                        String Email = c.getString("Email");
                        db.ajouterMed(Cle, Nom, Prenom, Adresse, Numero, Lat, Lng, Specialite, Email);
                        //inserting values in database
                    }

                }  
            }}} catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

call it like this

```
new updateMed().execute();
```

the php page

```
    <?php
include('connect.php');
$response = array(); 

if (isset($_POST['param1']) && isset($_POST['param2']) ){ 
 $Cle=$_POST['Param1']; // ... add here your params and there values

if ($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `med` where `Cle`>'$Cle'")) {


if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
    $response["med"] = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $med = array();
        $med["Cle"] = intval($row["Cle"]);
        $med["Nom"] = $row["Nom"];
        $med["Prenom"] = $row["Prenom"];
        $med["Adresse"] = $row["Adresse"];
        $med["Numero"] = $row["Numero"];
        $med["Lat"] = $row["Lat"];
        $med["Lng"] = $row["Lng"];
        $med["Specialite"] = $row["Specialite"];
        $med["Email"] = $row["Email"]; 
        // push single record into final response array

        array_push($response["med"], $med);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1; 
    $response["message"] ="Mise à jour telechargée"; 
    $response["type"] ="update";  

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no record found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "La BD est à jour";
    $response["type"] ="update";  
    // echo no record JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
}}else{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Erreur cle manquée";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

this is my function to insert in database

```
 public void ajouterMed(Integer Cle,String Nom,String Prenom,String Adresse,String Numero,String Lat,String Lng,String Specialite,String Email) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = lireMedecin();
    if (c.getCount() == 0) {
        db.execSQL("Insert Into Med values('" + 0 + "','" + Nom + "','" + Prenom + "','" + Adresse + "','" + Numero + "','" + Lat + "','" + Lng + "','" + Specialite + "','" + Email + "','" + Cle + "');");
    } else {
        c.moveToLast();
        Integer i = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0));
        String s = Integer.toString(i + 1);
        db.execSQL("Insert Into Med values('" + s + "','" + Nom + "','" + Prenom + "','" + Adresse + "','" + Numero + "','" + Lat + "','" + Lng + "','" + Specialite + "','" + Email + "','" + Cle + "');");
    }
}
```